# Wordpress search custom form

Tags: wordpress

I have standard search form in on my WP.

```
<form method="get" id="searchform" action="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>">
    <label for="s" class="assistive-text"><?php _e( 'Search', 'twentyeleven' ); ?></label>
    <input type="text" class="field" name="s" id="s" placeholder="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Search', 'twentyeleven' ); ?>" />
    <input type="submit" class="submit" name="submit" id="searchsubmit" value="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Search', 'twentyeleven' ); ?>" />
</form>
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Simply create a `searchform.php` in your theme-folder.
Copy the php-tags from the standard code, to achieve similar behaviour. Also don't change the name-attributes, or it won't work.

```
<form role="search" method="get" id="searchform" action="<?php echo home_url( '/' ); ?>">
  <div><label class="screen-reader-text" for="s">Search for:</label>
    <input type="text" value="" name="s" id="s" />
    <input type="submit" id="searchsubmit" value="Search" />
  </div>
</form>
```

See the example on this [Codex page](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_search_form#Examples)

Comment: Do I have to copy this two times?
 <input type="text" value="" name="s" id="s" />
I have a search widget and I still can't see 2 fields.